# Model property isn't updated for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Working on my MVC assignment, I've come across having to tell JavaScript when some data is ready.
I've attempted to do this through assigning the model to the view and calling upon `@Model.property_name` in the JavaScript, but it appears that whenever I call `@Model.property_name`the value of this bool isn't updated, even though the model did update it in the background.

Here's the code:

Model

```
public class saveModel
    {
        public bool dataReady;
        // Members

        public void SaveRoute()
        {
            // Stuff

            // Finally, changing the bool
            dataReady = true;
        }
    }
```

View

```
// Stuff
<script>
        function sleep(ms) {
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        }

        async function checkDataReady()
        {
            var ready = @Json.Encode(Model.dataReady);
            while (ready != true) {
                console.log(ready);
                console.log("Sleeping");
                await sleep(3000);
                ready =  @Json.Encode(Model.dataReady);
            }
            // When data is ready
            showDataMined();
        }

        // On page-load, check if data is ready
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 
checkDataReady(); });
</script>
```

I would expect that when the model changes the `dataReady` property to true, that the next time the loop in `checkDataReady()` is traversed that the var ready would be assigned to true, however, it is always assigned to false.

I made sure the bool is in fact assigned to true, so I'm stumped.

Comment: How do we know if the updated model is available within the view? How is the model getting updated?

Comment: those 2 @Json.Encode calls are going to render the same value. These are rendered when the cshtml gets rendered to html. If you do a view source in your browser you will see this.You may wish to change that 2nd Json.Encode to ready = true.

Comment: I don't wish to change that Json.Encode to ready = true however, since it might not always be appropriate.
The value of dataReady changes when the model is done with the computations, so I want the value in the JavaScript to change in turn.


Also, even when manually calling showDataMined from the console, the property it calls is also empty. 


Is there no way to use model properties as they get updated?
Do all Model.Property calls strictly use the values rendered to the html on page load?